# Re-applying filters in a Google Drive spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Google Drive spreadsheet that's acting as a to-do list.  There's a column for whether I've completed the item represented by a row; when I have, I mark that column as complete.  Since I don't need to see items I've completed, I've set a filter (via the toolbar icon plus the pull-down buttons that appear on each column's first cell) that hides anything marked as complete.

When I mark a row as complete, that row stays in my (filtered) list despite the fact that it no longer meets my filter.  I'd like it to immediately get filtered when that cell is edited, which seems like it should be easy to do with a trigger, except I have no idea how to force the filter to re-evaluate itself from a script.  Sorting doesn't do the trick (I tried that already); is there a way to programmatically force the re-evaluation of the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Apps Script cannot interact with Sheet filters (yet). You may want to *star* this feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524), to receive updates and kind of vote for it.

Comment: I'll do that, though the impending closing of Google Code makes me question whether it'll have any effect.